# Why is my Iomega StorCenter Not Recognized Using port 8888 -- Airport Extreme Configuration?

Tags: router, nas, storage, dhcp, network-shares

**Problem**

I have an Iomega StorCenter ix2-200d, but I think this question would apply to the Iomega StorCenter products in general as I am at the very begining of the setup process.

**Environment**

The configuration consists of various clients connected to a Mac AirPort Extreme using DHCP.  I have tried the setup of the StorCenter from both Windows XP and Mac OS clients without success.

**Steps Tried**

With the StorCenter plugged into my router . . .

Running the "Setup Tool"  opens a web browser that goes to *`http://localhost:8888/`* After clicking through the few wizard screens that tell you to plug in the network cable, power cord, and finally attempts to detect the device, I receive the following error message:

> "Sorry. Please confirm that all cables
>   have been properly connected, your
>   router is working properly, and the
>   Iomega StorCenter device has been
>   turned on before clicking Next again.
>   Click the Retry button to try again.
>   Click the Back button to start the
>   install again."

I have also tried setting the device up with an Ethernet cable connected directly to a computer.  In all attempts, I used the included network cable as well as two others, rebooted everything, and retried all steps.  I also reset the settings on the router and reconfigured it.  I am wondering if this is something related to DHCP settings on the router?

Thanks for the help!

-bn

Comment: Hi bn. I think you might have better luck over at our sister-site http://www.superuser.com. I have requested that this question be migrated there, so there's no need for you to re-enter it.

Comment: Thanks Farseeker, I was thinking about that today after having posted it, but was sure at the time where to put it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question from someone who has experience with using the StorCenter products.

The problem was the drives not being fully seated in the disk enclosure.  The StorCenter will not report status, or provide any indication of this being the problem.  So, with the device powered off, pulling out and pushing in each drive solved the problem.

-bn

Answer (score 0):

when you have it plugged into the router, does the router report it as getting an IP address?

alternatively (or if the router doesn't do DHCP logging nicely):

If your IP address was 192.168.5.2(netmask 255.255.255.0) then `nmap -sP 192.168.5.0/24` will try and ping all the hosts on your network, and might give you an idea of whether the StoreCenter is showing up anywhere.

---

The other idea that jumps to mind is that the StorCenter might have a fixed IP address on a different network subnet than the one your computer is sat on. You could always plug it back into the ethernet port and then use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see if its broadcasting any information.